# SharePoint send email with javascript on add list item

Tags: javascript, list, email, sharepoint-2013

I like to send an email to the administrator when a user adds a item to my List. I already changed the NewForm for the list and execute the add item with:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', retrieveListItems);
```

Now in my SharePoint the email notification on Lists has been disabled by the company. So I'd like some code to send an email automatically after the user added an item. 
I already have the username of the person who added the item.

```
var loginName = "";
var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
GetCurrentUser();

function GetCurrentUser() {
var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";
```

The email has to be send to an address of the companies outlook server. An SMTP can be used.

Marco

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little code snippet to send email using javascript.

```
function getUserEmail(){
 $.ajax({
   url:spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid("+_spPageContextInfo.userId+")?$select=Email", 
   headers:{"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose","content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"}, 
   success:function(result){ 
      var email = result.d.Email;
      sendEmail("xxxx@email.com", email, "body", "subject");
   }
  });
}

function sendEmail(from, to, body, subject) {

    var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
    var urlTemplate = siteurl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: urlTemplate,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'properties': {
                '__metadata': {
                    'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties'
                },
                'From': from,
                'To': {
                    'results': [to]
                },
                'Body': body,
                'Subject': subject
            }
        }),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    });
}
```

But it also depends on your scenario. Can you give us more details about:

> I already changed the NewForm for the list and execute the add item with:

How did you proceed?
Are you working on on-premise or online instance?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it was still possible to set an alert on a list when an item was added. So that solved my problem.